# Cassandra data modeling for server time series metrics

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I gonna collect server metrics, such as OS metrics, Java processes info etc, every second.

For example JSON:

```
{
  "localhost": {
    "os": {
      "cpu": 4,
      "memory": 16
    },
    "java": {
      "jvm": {
        "vendor": "Oracle"
      },
      "heap": 4,
      "version": 1.8
    }
  }
}
```

What is the best data model for such kind of data?
Should I store every type of metrics in separate table or all in one?

Comment: In Cassandra everything starts with question - how would you query the data... I recommend to take DS220 course on the http://academy.datastax.com

Comment: For instance, I have metrics from 1000 servers, I want to query all metrics from 1000 servers every second.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to translate each individual metric into a dotted string, so that your JSON:

```
{
  "localhost": {
    "os": {
      "cpu": 4,
      "memory": 16
    },
    "java": {
      "jvm": {
        "vendor": "Oracle"
      },
      "heap": 4,
      "version": 1.8
    }
  }
}
```

Turns into this:

```
Host        Key               Value
localhost   os.cpu            4
localhost   os.memory         16
localhost   java.jvm.vendor   Oracle
localhost   java.heap         4
localhost   java.version      1.8
```

Not shown above is a timestamp column. The primary key would be host+key+timestamp. If you don't need to be able to query by individual host, you could lump the hostname into the key, i.e. key=localhost.os.cpu.

The precise details of your querying needs weigh heavily into whether this is the right choice.